# Intents in mvvmcross on Mono for Android

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, monodevelop, mvvmcross, xamarin-studio

I've recently upgraded to Xamarin Studio running on Windows.  I have a simple implementation of the mvvmcross TipCalculator tutorial that ran nicely on Android and the various Windows flavors.  After I upgraded, the Android application started throwing NullReferenceExceptions in the Main activity (below):

```
[Activity(Label = "TipCalculator.Android", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class TipCalculatorActivity : MvxBindingActivityView<TipCalculatorViewModel>

{
    protected override void OnViewModelSet()
    {
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.TipView);//Throws NullReferenceException
    }

}
```

After doing some digging into the mvvmcross code, I found this method in the MvxAndroidViewsContainer class:

```
public virtual IMvxViewModel Load(Intent intent, Type viewModelTypeHint)
{
    if (intent == null)
    {
        // TODO - some trace here would be nice...
        return Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelTypeHint) as IMvxViewModel;
        //return null;
    }

    if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionMain)
    {
        // TODO - some trace here would be nice...
        return Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelTypeHint) as IMvxViewModel;
    }

    if (intent.Extras == null)
    {
        // TODO - some trace here would be nice...
        return Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelTypeHint) as IMvxViewModel;
        //return null;
    }

    IMvxViewModel mvxViewModel;
    if (TryGetEmbeddedViewModel(intent, out mvxViewModel))
        return mvxViewModel;

    return CreateViewModelFromIntent(intent);
}
```

In the original code, there are two cases that return null.  In each of these I replaced that with a call to Activator.CreateInstance().

I'm not sure what the rationale behind the original implementation is, and I'm a bit concerned I've broken something.  Can anybody shed some light on why there are cases this method returns null and whether I've broken something fundamental in mvvmcross?

Comment: what was 'the issue' that these things solved? For droid I'm not seeing any particular issues - but I'm using vs rather than xs and am on a pc (is your code on a mac?)

Comment: if you need to talk at a more general 'Thoughts?' level then msybe try switching to http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/1549/pcls-and-mvvmcross-in-the-new-tools - stackoverflow is wonderful for specific detailed q&a points. But it's not so good for more general discussions :)

Comment: Sorry!  Should have been more specific...my original activity class just had an OnViewModelSet() method with a call to SetContentView.  That worked great in the last version of the tooling, but bombed with a NullReferenceExceptpion after I upgraded.  I did some digging and found your post indicating an Oncreate() method would help in certain scenarios -> although the scenario didn't match mine I gave it a whirl, which eventually led me to the Load() method in IMvxViewModel.  I continued to get the NullReferenceException until I made the changes to that method indicated above.

Comment: So my question really is - what have I potentially broken by making those edits?  To answer your other questions, I'm using both VS and XS -> VS for deeper debugging since the debugging experience is much better (although much slower), and XS for general development and test.  No Macs (yet), although I am waiting for a Mac to come to my office so I can configure it as an iOS build server.  Are you using Xamarin Studio, or the older Mono Develop tooling?  I didn't have trouble until I upgraded.

Comment: One last update - I realized after re-reading this thread that the OnCreate() stuff I added is non-standard (ish), so I just commented that out and tried again.  Everything works fine with the changes I made to the mvvmcross lib, but if I switch them back the problem returns.  Quite curious to hear your thoughts on the update and what impacts it may have.

Comment: I think you've really lost me :) What was the NullReferenceException? Which was the post talked about OnCreate()? I believe I'm working in fairly similar tools and I'm not seeing the same exception (not that I know of anyway!). Please don't reply too long in comments - too hard to read :) Maybe try editing the question with the details of what the NullRef was? What the post was? etc - or switch to chat or forum. I am trying to help - honest!

Comment: LOL - edited to try and be more clear.  I'm really just looking for guidance from you on whether I've done something spectacularly stupid.  I appreciate the assist!

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your current issue has to do with the new Xamarin tools. Your description of NullReferenceExceptions, changed files and blog posts lost me...

I'd guess that quite a few things may have changed in your development setup and maybe in your app as well. If you can work back out one step at a time maybe then you'll be able to work out what the key change is.

It does sound like your code change might fix might fix your current problem - but it's definitely a patch applied after the problem (whatever it is) has occurred, so it's not something I'd want to do in the core code right now.

---

In terms of the code you've asked about:

```
        if (intent == null)
        {
            // TODO - some trace here would be nice...
            return null;
        }
```

This first null will only occur if the Activity has somehow been created without an Intent - which I guess isn't happening? (Unless maybe somewhere in your current tooling setup this is somehow being set as null?)

---

```
        if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionMain)
        {
            // TODO - some trace here would be nice...
            return Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelTypeHint) as IMvxViewModel;
        }
```

This is the normal path for a directly launched activity - this activity will have no extra parameters for constructing the ViewModel.

Generally this path doesn't happen in many MvvmCross apps - most apps launch via a splashscreen activity.

---

```
        if (intent.Extras == null)
        {
            // TODO - some trace here would be nice...
            return null;
        }
```

For any other activity, Mvx should have inserted some special ViewModel information into the Extras - so there is no way Extras should be null... If this is happening, then what code is creating the activity?

---

```
IMvxViewModel mvxViewModel;
if (TryGetEmbeddedViewModel(intent, out mvxViewModel))
    return mvxViewModel;

return CreateViewModelFromIntent(intent);
```

This is the normal launch path for an activity that has been navigated to.

---

If it helps, here's the latest v3 code - which has some trace added (but also adds the confusion of savedState - ignore this for now!):

```
    public virtual IMvxViewModel Load(Intent intent, IMvxSavedState savedState, Type viewModelTypeHint)
    {
        if (intent == null)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Null Intent seen when creating ViewModel");
            return null;
        }

        if (intent.Action == Intent.ActionMain)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Creating ViewModel for ActionMain");
            return Activator.CreateInstance(viewModelTypeHint) as IMvxViewModel;
        }

        if (intent.Extras == null)
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace(MvxTraceLevel.Error, "Null Extras seen on Intent when creating ViewModel - this should not happen - have you tried to navigate to an MvvmCross View directly?");
            return null;
        }

        IMvxViewModel mvxViewModel;
        if (TryGetEmbeddedViewModel(intent, out mvxViewModel))
        {
            MvxTrace.Trace("Embedded ViewModel used");
            return mvxViewModel;
        }

        MvxTrace.Trace("Loading new ViewModel from Intent with Extras");
        return CreateViewModelFromIntent(intent, savedState);
    }
```